# Laravel : Task Scheduling [ In Parallel ]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have multiple tasks that need to be done every hour or two. All of them have been scheduled via Laravel using below comamnds as cron jobs

```
$schedule->command('email:notifications1')
            ->cron('15 * * * * *');
$schedule->command('email:notifications2')
            ->cron('15 * * * * *');
$schedule->command('email:notifications3')
            ->cron('15 * * * * *');
```

**Issue:**
All of the above tasks are pretty time consuming & it seems from the results that these tasks are not running in parallel. And each tasks runs after the previous has ended.

**Requirment**
How can i run them in parallel? I want all tasks to be executed (in parallel) as soon as the clock tick the specified time.

*Laravel Version 5*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Laravel scheduler can only run one command at a time because of the limitations of PHP.

You could, however, add the cronjobs directly in your crontab file, this way, they will be executed in parallel in separate processes.

```
15 * * * * * php /path/to/artisan email:notifications1
15 * * * * * php /path/to/artisan email:notifications2
15 * * * * * php /path/to/artisan email:notifications3
```

Another way to fix this is to let the jobs start at another time. Because a new php process is started every minute by the cron job, these do not affect each other.

For example:

```
$schedule->command('email:notifications1')
            ->cron('5 * * * * *');
$schedule->command('email:notifications2')
            ->cron('10 * * * * *');
$schedule->command('email:notifications3')
            ->cron('15 * * * * *');
```

Comment: The first option is working well for my case. Second option is not working as expected. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The first option deprives you the ability to control the versions of the schedule together with the versions of the code

Comment: Laravel can run multiple commands at a time if you let the commands run in the background.

Answer (score 11):

You can easily have multiple parallel commands running if you add `runInBackground()` (introduced in Laravel 5.2) to the chain.
Like this:

```
$schedule->command('email:notifications1')
            ->cron('15 * * * * *')->runInBackground();
$schedule->command('email:notifications2')
            ->cron('15 * * * * *')->runInBackground();
$schedule->command('email:notifications3')
            ->cron('15 * * * * *')->runInBackground();
```

This creates a new process in the background so the Scheduler doesn't have to wait until the command executes. This doesn't even interfere with the `withoutOverlapping()` method because that works with mutex files.

Now you also have the benefit of having your commands in version control.

Comment: This is great but not available on Laravel Version 5

Comment: @Paranoid Android It was introduced from Laravel 5.2.  At the time I answered this question the EOL of 5.1 was well overdue. So I could presume everyone reading this answer was at least using 5.2. 

You shouldn't be using 5.1 or lower at the moment, that poses a security risk.