# Is Laravel Scheduler stopping execution after repeated errors?

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

In my Laravel scheduler I have many lines like the following

```
 $schedule->command('commandname01')->everyMinute();
 $schedule->command('commandname02')->everyMinute();
 $schedule->command('commandname03')->everyMinute();
```

I have noticed that some command e.g. commandname02 is not running anymore
but commandname01 and commandname03 are running.

How could I restore the full commands execution?

Note: if i log into my container and run

```
php artisan commandname02
```

It will work fine.

Suspects:

- Is it possible that Laravel scheduler stops executing one of the commands if it goes repeatedly on error?
- Is it possible that, if commandname01 takes too long, commandname02 will be skipped at same minute execution?

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible that, if commandname01 takes too long, commandname02 will be skipped at same minute execution?"

Yes and the reason is that command are not executed in parallel (***multithread is not natively available in PHP***) but sequentially within scheduler

So if commandname01 takes more than 60" for exec. commandname02 execution will be skipped in the same minute.

Resource: [Laravel : Task Scheduling [ In Parallel ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217770/laravel-task-scheduling-in-parallel)

Solution I adopted and recommend, as provided in link above, it's to implement parallel task leveraging on crontab.

Launch batches to be run in parallel  like:

```
 * * * * * php /var/www/artisan batch01   >> /var/log/laravel-scheduler.log

 * * * * * php /var/www/artisan batch02   >> /var/log/laravel-scheduler.log
```

And in batchNN commands just call your commands that can be run sequentially