# Running multiple tasks at the same time

Tags: laravel

There is a code that runs the command according to the schedule, but I noticed that they are not executed simultaneously, but after the previous one is completed, how to make the tasks run simultaneously

```
    $tasks = Profile::where('active', true)->whereNotNull('frequency')->get();

    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $frequency = $task->frequency;
        $schedule->call(function () use ($task) {
            Artisan::call('exchange:run', [
                '--id' => $task->id
            ]);
        })->$frequency();
    }
```

I have the code in the schedule method of the file Kernel.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`runInBackground()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#background-tasks) method:

```
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $frequency = $task->frequency;
        $schedule->call(function () use ($task) {
            Artisan::call('exchange:run', [
                '--id' => $task->id
            ]);
        })->runInBackground()->$frequency();
    }
```

Comment: Mike. Not work...

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217770/laravel-task-scheduling-in-parallel